# Error building Sitecore project on TFS2015

Tags: sitecore, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, sitecore8

I just installed TFS2015 on a new server (locally) and now I'm trying to set up TFS2015 builds to replicate my xaml builds and I'm getting an error that I don't understand. Here's the error:

Build started 8/31/2016 12:36:33 PM.
     1>Project "C:\Agent_work\5\s\Source\BOTWSitecore.sln" on node 1 (Clean 
target(s)).
     1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
         Building solution configuration "release|any cpu".
C:\Program Files 
(x86)\MSBuild\HedgehogDevelopment\SitecoreProject\v9.0\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets(141,5): Error : The build output path must be relative to the TDS project root.
     1>Project "C:\Agent_work\5\s\Source\BOTWSitecore.sln" (1) is building 
"C:\Agent_work\5\s\Source\BOTWTDS\BOTWTDS.scproj" (11) on node 2 (Clean 
target(s)).
    11>C:\Program Files 
(x86)\MSBuild\HedgehogDevelopment\SitecoreProject\v9.0\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets(141,5): **error : The build output path must be relative to the TDS project root.** [C:\Agent_work\5\s\Source\BOTWTDS\BOTWTDS.scproj]
    11>Done Building Project "C:\Agent_work\5\s\Source\BOTWTDS\BOTWTDS.scproj" 
(Clean target(s)) -- FAILED.
     1>Done Building Project "C:\Agent_work\5\s\Source\BOTWSitecore.sln" (Clean target(s)) -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.
       "C:\Agent_work\5\s\Source\BOTWSitecore.sln" (Clean target) (1) ->
       "C:\Agent_work\5\s\Source\BOTWTDS\BOTWTDS.scproj" (Clean target) (11) ->
       (SitecoreBuildClean target) -> 
         C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\HedgehogDevelopment\SitecoreProject\v9.0\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets(141,5): **error : The build output path must be relative to the TDS project root.** [C:\Agent_work\5\s\Source\BOTWTDS\BOTWTDS.scproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:01.06
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: VSBuild
******************************************************************************
The given path's format is not supported.
******************************************************************************
Finishing Build
******************************************************************************
Worker Worker-03d1961b-0fe4-478f-9fa1-2d25cb7cfcb4 finished running job 
03d1961b-0fe4-478f-9fa1-2d25cb7cfcb4

**Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **install TDS on the build server** or **provide the build server with the files MSBuild uses to build your TDS project**. Those files can be found on any machine with TDS installed on it at the location specified in the error. You will need everything in the folder with the .targets file.

You'd better to make sure the environment on your build sever(build agent) are as same as your local. This will greatly reduce the risk of build failures. If it's still not work after TDS installed, you can try to build manually on the build agent ( machine) not through tfs to narrow down the issue whether related to agent environment or the TFS build definition settings.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but TDS is already installed on the build server in the location specified in the error (see image ![here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ms6jzm9uywwp476/hedgehogdirectory.jpg?dl=0).)

Comment: Are you using some publish target. Is there any publishing target defined that doesn't exist in your target? And you can also try to increase the default timeout in the config file. The config files is called “HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Tasks.Dll.config”.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the same issue, but I tried building locally and realized that I hadn't installed TDS for TFS2015. So I downloaded it and installed it and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks the same as Narasimha's issue in this link: [AUTOMATING SITECORE DEPLOYMENTS WITH TFS AND TDS](https://theagilecoder.wordpress.com/2013/01/26/automating-sitecore-deployments-with-tfs-and-tds/) and following is the workaround:

> I came to know from hedgehog that this is a tds error and they sent me
>   below message. In order to avoid this error, a line inside the TDS
>   .targets file, which checks the output directory, needs to be
>   commented out. Assuming that you have already TDS installed on your
>   build server, the .targets file is located at “C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\HedgehogDevelopment\SitecoreProject\v9.0\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets”.